# Hide show div angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angular-material

I am trying to hide and show div on each button click. Basically, if the first button is clicked show the first div... if the second div is clicked show the second div. My issue is that it shows and hides div only ONCE.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div layout="row" flex layout-align="center">
    <md-button ng-click="div1=true">Div 1</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="div2=true">Div 2</md-button>
  </div>
  <section layout="row">
    <div ng-hide="div2" ng-show="div1" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 1</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="div1" ng-show="div2" id="div2" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Also want first div to show on page load, so tried this:

```
#div2 {
  display:none;
}
```

but now it won't switch to `#div2` at all

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fsxa8xcc/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-init` to initialise the default state, and then use just one variable to define which one is visible.

```
<div ng-app="sandbox" ng-init="visibleDiv='div1'">
  <div layout="row" flex layout-align="center">
    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div1'">Div 1</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="visibleDiv='div2'">Div 2</md-button>
  </div>
  <section layout="row">
    <div ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div1'" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 1</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="visibleDiv == 'div2'" id="div2" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fsxa8xcc/1/

Answer (score 1):

After the first click, you set both `div1` and `div2` as `true`. But you have `ng-hide="div2" ng-show="div1"` where `ng-show` and `ng-hide` both will be always `true`.

I have updated your fiddle and changed your code as below.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/fsxa8xcc/2/

*Note*: On load, they both are invisible and if you want to show one of them you can use `ng-init="show=div1"`

```
<div ng-app="sandbox">
  <div layout="row" flex layout-align="center">
    <md-button ng-click="show='div1'">Div 1</md-button>
    <md-button ng-click="show='div2'">Div 2</md-button>
  </div>
  <section layout="row">
    <div ng-show="show=='div1'" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 1</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="show=='div2'" id="div2" flex>
      <md-card>
        <md-card-content>
          <p>This is Div 2</p>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```